# After launching Docker Desktop, all Images and Containers are no longer available

Tags: docker

Environment
Ubuntu 20.04

I have been using the CLI Docker environment, but I tried Docker Desktop.

I originally had a CLI Docker environment on my PC and added Docker Desktop to it.

When I started Docker Desktop, I found that all the Images and Containers that I had been able to use were missing.

After that, I typed the following commands from the terminal, but none of the Images appeared.

```
docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

When I type the same command with Docker Desktop closed, I get the following error message

```
docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/MYNAME/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

But I think it originally connected to the following socket.

```
unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

CLI version of Docker Engine seems to be running as shown below.
(This is confirmed with DockerDesktop closed.)

```
sudo systemctl status docker
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-12 12:18:16 JST; 34min ago
```

Does this mean that Docker Desktop has installed an additional DockerEngine internally and that is now the default?

I also get same error message when I try to use docker from the CLI even after uninstalling Docker Desktop.

```
docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/MYNAME/.docker/desktop/docker.sock.
```

Can this be fixed by changing a setting somewhere?